# How to handle auto renewal subscription if app closes in between?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to handle situation if in the in-app auto renewal plan purchase flow app closed/crashed after apple done their part of transaction and Storekit's delegate yet not called.

```
#pragma mark - SKPaymentTransactionObserver

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *)transactions {

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                [self handlePurchasingStateTransaction:transaction inQueue:queue];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self handlePurchasedStateTransaction:transaction inQueue:queue];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self handleFailedStateTransaction:transaction inQueue:queue];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self handleRestoredStateTransaction:transaction inQueue:queue];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
                [self handleDeferredStateTransaction:transaction inQueue:queue];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Our iOS app provides auto-renewal based subscriptions, when user purchase any plan then we will update our server about the signed in user and their plan and provide the services based on that plan.

We are doing receipt validation for identify the app store account, our app is using one to one relationship with our app's signed in(sign up by email) user and app store account(identify account by their original transaction id in purchase receipt).

If user first time purchasing the plan then we don't have their original transaction id.

We want to identify that paid user and provide the service based on the plan.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Please post your exact problem including any relevant code snippets, what you have tried so far and what particular issue you are having. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: I already mentioned in the title and in first line that while purchasing any plan user redirect to apple's server and done the steps now after successfully purchasing, if some connection lost or any crash occurred  while executing our app's code then how would we handle that scenario because user end he purchased the plan but flow broke so we didn't update our logic behalf of that.

Comment: The transaction will be in the payment queue in a pending state until you complete it.  You should not call complete transaction until you have successfully performed all required processing. That way if there is a crash or network problem the transaction will be retried when the user relaunches your app.  You should ensure that establishing the payment queue observer is one of the first things your app does after launch. You should also include a restore purchase button so that it is easy for the user to manually retry things.